# How to put Bokeh interactive maps on a Website?

Tags: python, html, bokeh

How to do upload my interactive bokeh maps I created on a website? I read the documentation and used the file_html function to create the html code, but all the functionality does not work like the select drop down, and sliders. What is the best way to share it on a website?

This is the warning I received.

```
This is the Warning I received. WARNING:bokeh.embed.util: You are generating 
standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python callbacks (i.e. 
with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work. Only JavaScript 
callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more information on  
JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh , see:

http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html
```

Comment: what do you have in HTML? Maybe it can't read JavaScript files. Or maybe it needs Python code for this so you can't put only HTML on server but you have to run full Bokeh server.

Comment: I believe this is the issue but I am uncertain how to approach it. This is the Warning I received.   

WARNING:bokeh.embed.util:
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.

Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more
information on JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh, see:

Comment: always put error message in question. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: it only confirm that you can't use only HTML but you have to run bokeh server. It should be in documentation or any tutorial.

Comment: documentation [Running a Bokeh Server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make that error message as self-contained as possible. I am not sure what else can be added to it, but suggestions are welcome. There are two scenarios:

#### Standalone output

This is purely HTML and JS content, that has no connection with any running python process. It is most often generated with `output_file` and `show` (or `save`), but it's also what you get if you use the lower level `file_html` function. Since there is no Python process anywhere after the output is created, *there is no possible way for "real" Python callbacks to function, at all*. In this case, the only possible callbacks that can work are JavaScript ones, e.g. `CustomJS` added with `js_on_change` or `js_on_event`. That's because the browser viewing the (purely HTML and JS) content does not know anything about Python, it only knows about JavaScript.

#### Bokeh Server Applications

This is a *continuously running Bokeh server* that serves Bokeh content, and, 
 most crucially: maintains an active connection to that content. That means that when some event happens, e.g. a slider changes, the Bokeh server can run *real Python callback code* in response. That is, in fact, the primary reason the Bokeh server exists: to *be the thing that runs real Python code* for an `on_change` or `on_event` callbacks.  If you want to run real Python code (e.g. Numpy or Pandas or whatever) in response to events, you must [run a Bokeh server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html).

Comment: I figured as much, but I am stilling learning python so I was wondering how much JavaScript I need to know. I am going to try to join some coding groups in my area probably be the best bet because I want to get a good grasp on Python before trying to move on to other things.

Comment: The common case of JS usage in Bokeh callbacks is just simple assignments to properties, or maybe an occasional `if`/`else`, similar or identical to what is demonstrated at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the generated site in a web browser and select "Inspect". Then open the "console" tab and you list of errors will be detailed there. My guess is that you are not referencing a javascript file correctly.